# Many SWFs, single font embed, without creating textfields through Actionscript?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, fonts, flash-cs5

Is it possible to embed a font in a single SWF to be used throughout many other SWFs, while maintaining the ability to do all the text arrangement and setup through the Flash IDE in those SWFs?

I know I can retrieve a font from an external SWF, register it, and use it in a new TextField. However it would be nice if I didn't have to create every text field in code.

For instance, the following is after loading in a SWF that has a font in it and calling the following using the name of that font:

```
Font.registerFont();
```

The original text field will show nothing, while the newly creating one USING THE FORMAT FROM THE ORIGINAL, shows perfectly fine.

```
        var format:TextFormat = onStageTextField.getTextFormat();

        onStageTextField.embedFonts = true;
        onStageTextField.defaultTextFormat = format;
        onStageTextField.text = "My Text";

        var newTextField:TextField = new TextField();
        newTextField.width = 300;
        newTextField.embedFonts = true;
        newTextField.defaultTextFormat = format;
        newTextField.text = "My Text";
        contentMC.addChild(newTextField);
```

Answer (score 1):

I fear the short answer to your main question is "no." There's ways to embed font with code, and through the IDE, but I don't know of a way to do a hybrid approach like you describe.

An alternative approach:

In your main FLA Create MovieClips holding each style of textfield (or groups of textfields) you want to reuse, style and embed in the IDE. Name the child TextFields something like "txt". Give the MCs linkage ids. Now when you load your child SWF, create & add instances of the MCs for any textfields you need to display using flash.utils.getDefinitionByName(). Update the text in each instance like so: myMC.txt.text = "my text".

The above should work well for dynamic text in lots of fields. When you say "text arrangement"... are you talking about line-break adjustment?

Comment: I'm sorry but your example is pretty much the same as creating textfields manually in code. All I want is to be able to place the textfields in the IDE, but not have to include the filesize of the embed in each of my content SWFs. Seems like there has to be a way to avoid embedding the font everywhere. I know the font is available to the player, since when I create a new field it uses it just fine. Now how do I tell the on-stage field (with the SAME format) to use that font?